# Merge values in sql rows

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, unpivot

I am looking for ways to merge row values into one row where the column to merge is the same

Transform:

```
FK | F1 
========
3  | ABC    
3  | DEF
```

to

```
FK | F1    | F2
=================
3  | ABC   | DEF
```

Update:
I initially don`t know the values of F1. They might be everything, but I know they are unique for a given FK and they are varchars.

Update 2:
With your help I came to this query that will also add the FK for which there is only one value. I suppose it could be improved.

SELECT IFNULL(jointable.FK,`table`.FK) AS FK, IFNULL(jointable.F1,`table`.F1), jointable.F2 
FROM `table` 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT T1.FK, T1.F1, T2.F1 AS F2
    FROM `table` T1
    LEFT JOIN `table` T2 ON T1.FK = T2.FK
    WHERE T1.F1 <> T2.F1
    GROUP BY T1.FK
    ) as jointable
ON `table`.FK=jointable.FK
GROUP BY FK;

Comment: Which is your database? Oracle, SQL server, MySql etc.

Comment: do you only have 2 rows per ID or more?

Comment: Mysql is the database.

Comment: I have 1 or 2 F1(s) per FK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT FK
     , T1.F1
     , T2.F1 AS F2
FROM table T1
LEFT JOIN table T2 ON T1.FK = T2.FK AND T1.F1 <> T2.F1 --Criteria moved here
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is used since you mentioned that you have 1 or more values, which means the `INNER JOIN` could end up excluding rows.

The second criteria is to make sure you don't en up with rows like:

```
FK | F1    | F2
=================
3  | ABC   | ABC
```

Please be aware that in case of an `OUTER JOIN` (either `LEFT` or `RIGHT`) the join criteria is not the same as the filter criteria, and therefore I moved it above.

In SQL Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` over `FK`, maybe with an `ORDER BY`.

In MySQL you might be able to use it with a `GROUP BY` as you mentioned in comments, I am not sure it will work (at least not in SQL Server without an aggregate function or a CTE).

Here is a live test: http://ideone.com/Bu5aae

Comment: It works, but it produces two rows - first is "3 ABC DEF", second is "3 DEF ABC". I will try to group them to get the unique

Comment: I changed it to "SELECT T1.FK
     , T2.F1
     , T1.F1 AS F2
FROM `table` T1
LEFT JOIN `table` T2 ON T1.FK = T2.FK
WHERE T2.F1 <> T1.F1
GROUP BY FK" and it works for me. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I did a test. If there is only one value for FK it is missed. Do you know how could I add it to the result. I could have one or two values for each FK. When it is only one I should show it. If there are two I should merge them.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:

```
SELECT FK, CONCAT(T1.F1,'',T2.F1) AS Result
FROM table T1, table T2
WHERE T1.FK = T2.FK
```

Comment: This gives me values of 
3 ABCABC
3 ABCDEF
3 DEFABC
3 DEFDEF
etc. I would like to join them